# How can I use variable in external function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, variables, external

I get an input variable in main function. and I want to use this variable in the external function2 that it already is called as a external function again by function1(like the code below). but this variable is undefined at function2. please help me. thanks for all answers. this is an overview of my code:

```
int main ()
{
int boogh;
cin >> boogh;
function1 (x,y);
}

function1(int x,int y)
{.
 .
function2(w,z);
 .
 .
}

function2(int w, int z)
{
if (boogh>5)
    {.
     do some thing
     .
     .
    } 
}
```

the function1 and function2 are recursive

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the function?

Comment: Pass the variables into functions using arguments, and get variables back out using the `return` keyword. Notice that `function1` and `function2` don't have return types? That's your first red flag.

Comment: I want to use this in function2 not function1. how can I pass it in function2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is scoped within `main`, so you can't access it there. You need to get it (or a copy of it) into the scope of `function2`. One way is to pass it as a function parameter - to both functions, since it has to go through `function1` to reach `function2`:

```
void function1(int x, int y, int boogh) {
    //...
    function2(w, z, boogh);
    //...
}

void function2(int w, int z, int boogh) {
    if (boogh > 5) {  // the value is available here
        //...
    }
}

int main() {
    int boogh;
    cin >> boogh;
    function1(x,y,boogh);
}
```

Or you could encapsulate the variable and the function(s) that use it in a class:

```
struct thingy {
    int boogh;
    void function1(int x,int y) {
        //...
        function2(w, z);
        //...
    }
    void function2(int w,int z) {
        if (boogh > 5) { // class member accessible here
            //...
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    thingy t;
    cin >> t.boogh;
    t.function1(x,y);
}
```

Or you could use a global variable, but that's nearly always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the required variable to the functions either by value or by reference:

Passing by value for your case:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void function1(int x);
void function2(int x);

int main ()
{
    int boogh;
    cin>>boogh;
    function1 (boogh);
}

void function1(int x)
{
    function2(x);
}

void function2(int y)
{
    int boogh=y;
    if (boogh>5)
    {
        //do something here
    } 
}
```

Comment: those functions are recursive

Comment: what do you mean by recursivie?! you just need to pass a value between this functions.